# Refreshing page on backbone application causes error

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone application that displays a list of content. The application works fine when  navigating through it using the links etc, but I have noticed that when I refresh the browser in chrome i start to see an error saying 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null' This error is occurring on line 969 of backbone.js.

The code that is causing this error is being executed in a loop via a the following code :

```
this._checkUrlInterval = setInterval(this.checkUrl, this.interval);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? I am starting the backbone history using the following code :

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

My application is built with backbone, require.js and jquery mobile, however if I remove the jquery mobile dependancy I still see the same error so don't think it has anything to do with jquery mobile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Kind Regards

Brian

Comment: Where in your code are you executing your checkURL function? It sounds like the DOM isn't ready when it runs.

Comment: can you make sure you are running the latest version of backbone? I'm pretty sure the code you are pointing at is about ~100 lines further then the line you refer to

Comment: I don't execute the checkURL function myself, it is executed via a timer in backbone code itself. Line 1016 in backbone js (development version) is the line that starts the timer.

Comment: I am using version 0.9.2 which I believe is the latest version?

Comment: On further investigation this problem also only appears on a mac, weird?

Comment: When you refresh the page are you at a different URL then when you started? If so are you sure you are initializing your models or collections correctly?